# Value nil when creating a View

Tags: ios, swift, view

I have this code to do swipe across multiple views, but I get:

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

When I do `self.scrollView!.aaDubview(SurfView.view)`

Any suggestions?

```
class LoadViewController: UIViewController {

// Outlet used in storyboard
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView?;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    var SkateView :LoadSkateViewController =  LoadSkateViewController(nibName: "LoadSkateViewController", bundle: nil);
    var LongboardView :LoadLongboardViewController =  LoadLongboardViewController(nibName: "LoadLongboardViewController", bundle: nil);
    var SurfView :LoadSurfViewController =  LoadSurfViewController(nibName: "LoadSurfViewController", bundle: nil);

    self.addChildViewController(SurfView)
    self.scrollView!.addSubview(SurfView.view)
    SurfView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    self.addChildViewController(LongboardView)
    self.scrollView!.addSubview(LongboardView.view)
    LongboardView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    self.addChildViewController(SkateView)
    self.scrollView!.addSubview(SkateView.view)
    SkateView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


    var adminFrame :CGRect = SkateView.view.frame
    adminFrame.origin.x = adminFrame.width
    LongboardView.view.frame = adminFrame

    var BFrame :CGRect = LongboardView.view.frame
    BFrame.origin.x = 2*BFrame.width
    SurfView.view.frame = BFrame

    var scrollWidth: CGFloat  = 3 * self.view.frame.width
    var scrollHeight: CGFloat  = self.view.frame.size.height
    self.scrollView!.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, scrollHeight);
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

This code is generated by a Brendan Lee example code

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on that line, what's the value for the scroll view? I'm guessing you didn't set your scroll view up properly.

Comment: What @AdamPro13 said. This can easily happen when an `IBOutlet` isn't wired up correctly.